# How to direct maven to download Apache commons-io-2.4.jar?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to get Apache commons-io-2.4.jar installed directly using maven.

The POM snippet is as follows. Can anyone help me make it work?

POM Snippet:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What problems did you encounter with your POM?

Comment: The definition of repositories in this case is not necessary cause you have defined the already existing defaults (Maven Central) so you can omit this from your pom. How have you called Maven? How does the rest of the pom file look like?

Comment: I called mave using:  mvn clean install.  The rest is a top level pom where I have listed all the dependencies. It's working for all other but rejects this particular artifact :(

Comment: It seems I also need to learn how to post extremely large snippets :)

Comment: Solved. Was using a unsupported version on the top pom, redeclared the dependency with a type on another module. Removed the repeated dependency and corrected the version. Works like a charm. Thanks Cristik!